# JAVASCRIPT How to make API send out a number after using a command

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I make this API for FIVEM

```
srv.getPlayers().then(data => console.log(data))
```

log the players' amount to the command I want for example /stats would use that API to show the players when the command is running.
sorry if it's a dumb question.

this is what I came up with

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'stats') {
       message.channel.send(srv.getPlayers().then(data));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
srv.getPlayers().then(data => message.channel.send(data));
```

Comment: @DanThePvpGod Thanks for verifying my answer. please do upvote too.

Comment: Hi am i able to turn this into a message like "There is x amount of people online"

Comment: try this.
srv.getPlayers().then(data => message.channel.send('There is ' +  data + ' amount of people online'));