# JS Send out API message with text

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

how would i send a message with the API script that tells how many people are online.
Eg "there are x many people online"

API
`srv.getPlayers().then(data => message.channel.send(data));`

Comment: follow up on your original question. There is a lot of context missing here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993377/javascript-how-to-make-api-send-out-a-number-after-using-a-command

Answer (score 1):

@CygnusOlor Thanks for the context; really helped.

You can assign the data to a variable and manipulate that by utilising `async` / `await`.

```js
const players = await srv.getPlayers();
if (!players) return message.reply('Hmm. I couldn\'t find `players`!');
message.channel.send(`Players Online: \`${players}\``);
```